# Config setting for the threshold between single/multiple item handling?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

You know this slider that appears when you try to handle a stack of more than five items in the inventory?

I find that repeating the "Store" or "Sell" key is easier and faster to use, and really don't need the slider until I have a stack of 20 items or so. It's really cumbersome to use this slider when you want to dump half your stacks of potions and whatnot to your house.

Would it be possible to change the threshold at which it appears, through a config file or maybe the console?

Comment: He ... I've got the opposite "problem". I'd really like to have that dialog for 5 objects, but it only shows up with 6 or more. Anyway: you can use the *E* key to confirm the dialog, which significantly speeds up the use of the dialog.

Comment: +1 Good question. I've often been flying through a list of junk, pressing 'E' 3 or 4 times on stacks of various things. Then when a 6-stack comes up I instinctively press E 6 times and BOOM! I'm naked.

Comment: When I want to sell half a stack, or store the majority and keep a few on me, instead of pressing E multiple times I have to use left/right to adjust the slider and then press E. The slider is useful but more often than not, it breaks the flow for me. PS: This is a case where most RPGs/MMOs would let you Ctrl-click or Shift Click to split a stack. I like Skyrim's spartan interface, as it is much more immersive than that of your average MMO, I just wish the threshold for displaying the slider wasn't so low.

Comment: Hm.. E is great until you're trying to put food/ingredients somewhere and you find out you're eating it all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To anyone else who may be wondering, it appears to be a hardcoded variable in the ActionScript code for the interface.

See line 24 of [InventoryDefines.as](http://code.google.com/p/skyrimui/source/browse/src/common/InventoryDefines.as?name=vanillasky) (courtesy of the SkyUI code repo):

```
static var QUANTITY_MENU_COUNT_LIMIT: Number = 5;
```

I haven't found a config setting that matches. It is possible to recompile the code as a mod though...

**UPDATE**: It works! If you really want to change this you'll need Adobe Flash CS5 (ActionScript 2.0). I have zero experience with Flash so did this mostly out of curiosity. Figured it would be too minor a change to put on SkymrimNexus.

[Thanks to the hard work of the SkyUI mod team](http://code.google.com/p/skyrimui/), you can republish directly from the `.fla`  files. They went through all the flash files, decompiled them with Trillix (my guess) and cleaned /fixed the code as a working basis for the SkyUI mod. You can find the "un-modded" version of the game interface code in the *vanillasky* branch.

For this particular interface tweak, you'll want to edit *InventoryDefines.as* as described above. Then open itemcard.fla in Flash, and republish. Note that you'll have to provide the fonts (search on SkyrimNexus). Place the file in the Skyrim Data folder:

```
<Skyrim folder>/Data/Interface/inventory components/itemcard.swf
```

I've tested in game successfully with a limit of 10 instead of 5, trading with an innkeeper, my follower and interacting with a chest. Can't guarantee that it is 100% stable as that would require much more thorough testing ("ItemCard" appears during enchanting, alchemy, and a lot of other things).

Comment: I'll accept my answer, which although fairly technical... does work  and solves my problem. *blush*  If someone finds a better/easier method I will gladly accept that instead :)