# How can I remap the keybindings for containers in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

The interface for containers in Skyrim is driving me nuts. On the chest side, press <kbd>E</kbd> and you take the ingredient. Change to your inventory side, press <kbd>E</kbd> and you eat the item, instead of dropping it in to the box.

On the other hand, I have emptied the whole chest countless times, because the <kbd>R</kbd> key moves one item from your inventory into the container, but *all* items the other way round.

Is there any way to change this behavior? Mods like "[Interface Hard Coded Key Tweaks](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=88)" only seem to be able to change the whole group of functions a key can be bound to in different situations (meaning that I could bind "Take" *and* "Eat" on another key, but not on different keys).

Comment: This is really starting to annoy me.  I frequently quick travel back to Riverwood where I have five barrels that I use to categorize loot that I come to drop off.  These barrels are filled to the brim with ores, jewelry, magic items, igredients, etc.  I'll open one and think I am looking in my own inventory, so I'll highlight an item and press R to store, only R, in this case, TAKES ALL.  So I end up having to reload my previous autosave because it's actually quick to do that than to sort out all the items I accidentally took.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions I can think of:

- Check out the [SkyUI](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=3863) mod. It may alleviate the problem as it's more reliant on the mouse, however it doesn't replace all menus at this time (only the personal inventory screen).
- If you have Adobe Flash and with some programming experience I'm pretty sure you can separate those predefined controls into any keys you like. See my question [Config setting for the threshold between single/multiple item handling?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/config-setting-for-the-threshold-between-single-multiple-item-handling) for the basics of opening and editing the Interface files. You'll need a tool like [FOMM](http://www.fallout3nexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=640) to see inside the *Skyrim - Interface.bsa* file and find the correct directory structure to store your own "mod".

  You wouldn't be able to change the UI like SkyUI does without prior Flash experience. However as I have found out, it's fairly simple to edit the actionscript code and re-publish the files without touching anything else.

  **EDIT** If you're willing to hack the actionscript, see [line 62 of ContainerMenu.as](http://code.google.com/p/skyrimui/source/browse/src/containermenu/ContainerMenu.as?name=vanillasky#62)

Comment: Well the game apparently is hardcoded for a gamepad (ie. fewer controls). So on the actionscript side you can't actually add more controls (ie. separate R into two keys), because the main game calls one actionscript function to handle "R". In `ContainerMenu.as` however you can either comment out or change the call to  "TakeAllItems" into an "ItemTransfer".